# Error: expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: c

I was recently coding a short little fallout shelter survival game and I came across the error "expected ';' before '{' token". The error is around line 28, character 23:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {//setup changing variables
    int X = 0;
    int money = 300;
    int resources[10];
    resources[0] = 100;
    resources[1] = 200;
    printf("Welcome!\nFirst we will choose the extra supplies for your shelter!");
    while(X < 1)
    {
        //Setup the input
        char input[15];
        //Introduction:
        printf("You have $%d dollars\n1: Cards ($4)\n2: Ounce of Gold ($20)\n3: 10 Pounds of Spare Parts($20)\n4: Ham Radio ($75)\n5: Calendar ($5)\n6: Book of Blueprints ($10)\n7: (2 Gallons) Extra Water Storage ($6)\n8: (1 gallon) Fuel ($10)\n9:  Check Current Supplies\n10:Start\n", money);
        //Have player buy Items
        if(input == 1){ 
            if(money > 3){
                money = money - 4;
                resources[2] = resources[2] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased a deck of cards...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You can not afford this item\n");       
            }
        }
        elif(input == 2)
            {
            if(money > 19)
            {
                money = money - 20;
                resources[3] = resources[3] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased an Ounce of Gold...\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You do not have enough money\n");
            }
        }
        elif(input == 3){
            if(money > 19){
                money = money - 20;
                resources[4] = resources[4] + 10;
                printf("You have purchased 10 pounds of Scrap Parts...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You do not have enough money\n");
            }
        }
        elif(input == 4){
            if(money > 74){
                money = money - 75;
                resources[5] = resources[5] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased 1 Ham Radio...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You do not have enough money.\n");
            }
        }
        elif(input == 5)
        {
            if(money > 4)
            {
                money = money - 5;
                recources[6] = resources[6] + 1;
                printf("You have just purchased a calendar...\n");
            }
            else
            {
            printf("You can not afford the calendar.\n");
            }
        }
        elif(input == 6)
        {   
            if(money > 9){
                money = money - 10;
                resources[7] = resources[7] + 1;
                printf("You have just purchased a Book filled with Blueprints...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You can not afford the Book of Blueprints.\n"); 
            }
        }
        elif(input == 7){
            if(money > 5){
                int money = money - 6;
                int resources[8] = resources[8] + 2;
                printf("You have purchased 2 extra gallons of water storage...");
            }
            else{
                printf("You do not have enough money...");
            }
        }
        elif(input == 8){
            if(money > 9){
                money = money - 10;
                resources[9] = resources[9] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased one gallon of fuel...");
            }
            else{
                printf("You can not afford the fuel...");
            }
        }
        elif(input == 9){
            printf("You currently have:   \n%s Pounds of Food\n%s Gallons of Water\n%s Decks of Cards\n%s Ounces of Gold\n%s Pounds of Spare Parts\n%s Ham Radios\n%s Calendars\n%s Books of Blueprints\n%s Gallons of Fuel", resources[0], resources[8] + resources[1], resources[2], resources[3], resources[4],     resources[5], resources[6], resources[7], resources[9]);
            fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        }
        elif(input == 10){
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Input Invalid");
            fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        }
    }
    int h = 100;
    while(int h > 0)
    {
        printf("%d", h);
        h = h - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `elif` in C. You should use `else if`. There are many more errors...

Comment: `input` is uninitlailzed and comparasions like `input == 1` make no sense. You may want to change the type of `input` to `int` and use `scanf` to read input to that.

Comment: Oh, wow... Among the many problems a newb can make, that is probably pretty high up there... Thank you so much though, Pretty much every tutorial on if and else is C/C++ so I cant find the difference very often(bad excuses)... Thank you so much! One more thing, what are the parameters for scanf?

Comment: The code you provided is a little long (although it looks like you where able to get help), it is best if you can limit your code to the bits that are erroring or related to the error.

Comment: Yeah, that might reduce the unholy hatred of the masses... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot use `elif` in C. You should use `else if` instead.
- In `printf`, `%s` is not for printing integers. You should use `%d` instead.
- With `char input[15];`, comparations like `input == 1` make no sense. You may use `int char;`.
- `input` is uninitialized. You should read some data to that.
- `recources` is undefined. It should be typo of `resources`.
- I changed the type of `input` to `int` and put `scanf` before the branches, so remove `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);`
- Remove excess `int`s in `int money = money - 6;`, `int resources[8] = resources[8] + 2;` and `while(int h > 0)`
- The arguments aren't used, so change `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` into `int main(void)`. (optional to avoid warnings)

OK, now compile errors are gone.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{//setup changing variables
    int X = 0;
    int money = 300;
    int resources[10];
    resources[0] = 100;
    resources[1] = 200;
    printf("Welcome!\nFirst we will choose the extra supplies for your shelter!");
    while(X < 1)
    {
        //Setup the input
        int input;
        //Introduction:
        printf("You have $%d dollars\n1: Cards ($4)\n2: Ounce of Gold ($20)\n3: 10 Pounds of Spare Parts($20)\n4: Ham Radio ($75)\n5: Calendar ($5)\n6: Book of Blueprints ($10)\n7: (2 Gallons) Extra Water Storage ($6)\n8: (1 gallon) Fuel ($10)\n9:  Check Current Supplies\n10:Start\n", money);
        //Have player buy Items
        if(scanf("%d", &input) != 1) return 1;
        if(input == 1){ 
            if(money > 3){
                money = money - 4;
                resources[2] = resources[2] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased a deck of cards...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You can not afford this item\n");       
            }
        }
        else if(input == 2)
            {
            if(money > 19)
            {
                money = money - 20;
                resources[3] = resources[3] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased an Ounce of Gold...\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You do not have enough money\n");
            }
        }
        else if(input == 3){
            if(money > 19){
                money = money - 20;
                resources[4] = resources[4] + 10;
                printf("You have purchased 10 pounds of Scrap Parts...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You do not have enough money\n");
            }
        }
        else if(input == 4){
            if(money > 74){
                money = money - 75;
                resources[5] = resources[5] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased 1 Ham Radio...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You do not have enough money.\n");
            }
        }
        else if(input == 5)
        {
            if(money > 4)
            {
                money = money - 5;
                resources[6] = resources[6] + 1;
                printf("You have just purchased a calendar...\n");
            }
            else
            {
            printf("You can not afford the calendar.\n");
            }
        }
        else if(input == 6)
        {   
            if(money > 9){
                money = money - 10;
                resources[7] = resources[7] + 1;
                printf("You have just purchased a Book filled with Blueprints...\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("You can not afford the Book of Blueprints.\n"); 
            }
        }
        else if(input == 7){
            if(money > 5){
                money = money - 6;
                resources[8] = resources[8] + 2;
                printf("You have purchased 2 extra gallons of water storage...");
            }
            else{
                printf("You do not have enough money...");
            }
        }
        else if(input == 8){
            if(money > 9){
                money = money - 10;
                resources[9] = resources[9] + 1;
                printf("You have purchased one gallon of fuel...");
            }
            else{
                printf("You can not afford the fuel...");
            }
        }
        else if(input == 9){
            printf("You currently have:   \n%d Pounds of Food\n%d Gallons of Water\n%d Decks of Cards\n%d Ounces of Gold\n%d Pounds of Spare Parts\n%d Ham Radios\n%d Calendars\n%d Books of Blueprints\n%d Gallons of Fuel", resources[0], resources[8] + resources[1], resources[2], resources[3], resources[4],     resources[5], resources[6], resources[7], resources[9]);
        }
        else if(input == 10){
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Input Invalid");
        }
    }
    int h = 100;
    while(h > 0)
    {
        printf("%d", h);
        h = h - 1;
    }
}
```

---

> Enjoy!

Sorry, I didn't enjoy but got annoyed.

Comment: So sorry... I honestly just could not for the life of me figure this out... As I said, total noob...

Answer (score 0):

In c elif is not there. So, it gives that error.
Change the elif to else if and do validations.